# posting a query string and request payload while scraping

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, payload

I am trying to scrape cleverbot page that involves query string as well as request payload in its post method. How do i do it using requests in python3
the format in which it requests is this
Query string:

```
uc:"UseOfficialCleverbotAPI"
:""
Request payload:
stimulus=Hi.&cb_settings_scripting=no&islearning=1&icognoid=wsf&icognocheck=d4ef2eb8c791c8e8ebe3cc8d712a990f
```

How do I construct a payload?

Comment: Turn the payload to a dictionary and pass it to the `data` argument.

Comment: Just posting the payload as a dictionary ain't working